# Why are tensorflow .h5 model files of different size depending on which callback function stores it?

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow

If I want to train a tensorflow machine learning model and store the model after each training epoch on the hard drive, I can either use the following code (Python):

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model{epoch:08d}.h5', save_freq=1)
history = model.fit(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it), validation_data=test_it, validation_steps=len(test_it), epochs=numberOfTrainingEpochs, verbose=0, callbacks=checkpoint)
```

Or, however, I can use a custom, potentially more complex logic which decides when to save the model:

```
class CustomSaver(Callback):
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    self.model.save_weights("model_{}.h5".format(epoch))

saver = CustomSaver()
history = model.fit(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it), validation_data=test_it, validation_steps=len(test_it), epochs=numberOfTrainingEpochs, verbose=0, callbacks=saver)
```

Both files create .h5 files with the ML model, however, the first one creates file sizes of ca. 100 MB, whereas the second one creates file sizes of ca. 50 MB. What is the difference between those files and what is the cause for it?

Fyi, my model is a relatively simple CNN and defined as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint), the callback `ModelCheckpoint` saves the full model rather than only its weights by default. This behaviour is controlled by parameter `save_weights_only`. If you only want to save the weights, you can create the callback with

```py
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model{epoch:08d}.h5', save_freq=1, save_weights_only=True)
```